# Where can I find the schematics for the improved power grid?

Tags: mass-effect-3

[image]

Where can I find the schematics needed for the mission *Citadel: Improved Power Grid*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll find them on the "N7: Cerberus Attacks" mission on Tuchanka, they're in the control room for the cannon. Just grab them from there, or if you missed them you can usually buy those quest items in the Spectre shop on the Citadel.